# load Spring aggregator parametrs dynamically for tests

Tags: java, spring, cucumber, spring-integration, cucumber-junit

I'm using the aggregator of spring integration in my app.
I'm using cucumber to test the flow, and I want to make sure that the aggregator release
strategy is executed by the right parameters. I have 2 params for that strategy:
timeout, and size.
I would like to know if there is a way to load those parameters dynamically during the steps?
So far I'm lost about how to make it work.

Thanks,

Thank you Artem,

I used the `directFieldAccessor` and I'm trying to get the `release-strategy-expression` and `group-timeout` attributes from the aggregator, but the problem is that I can't access those fields:

```
public void setAggregatorConfiguration(String aggregatorName, int aggregationThreshold, long aggregationTimeout) { 
         EventDrivenConsumer aggregator = getAggregator(aggregatorName);           
         DirectFieldAccessor directFieldAccessor = new DirectFieldAccessor(aggregator); 
         directFieldAccessor.setPropertyValue("group-timeout", aggregationTimeout); 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have 2 params for that strategy: timeout, and size

Well, I guess you use `TimeoutCountSequenceSizeReleaseStrategy`. As we see those params are final in that class and they really can't be changed at runtime just with setters.

There is only one way to change such values at runtime - using `DirectFieldAccessor`.

However if you share more info about your use-case and config and unit test as well, we might find some other way to help you.

I've edited your post to add your code. No, you have to use the real property name, so it should be `groupTimeoutExpression`, not `group-timeout`. From other side there is a public setter on the matter: `AbstractCorrelatingMessageHandler.setGroupTimeoutExpression(Expression groupTimeoutExpression)`.

From other side you go a bit wrong way: any `MessageHandler` component (`<aggregator>`, `<service-activator>`) provides several component. Right, the root of them is a `AbstractEndpoint` (the parent of `EventDrivenConsumer`). But all of your desired properties are to the `AggregatingMessageHandler`, which can get from `BeanFactory` using its alias - `aggregatorName + ".handler"`.

`release-strategy-expression` is property of `ExpressionEvaluatingReleaseStrategy`, which you can change using `DirectFieldAccessor` on the `AggregatingMessageHandler`:

```
AggregatingMessageHandler handler = beanFactory.getBean(aggregatorName + ".handler", AggregatingMessageHandler.class);
DirectFieldAccessor directFieldAccessor = new DirectFieldAccessor(handler); 
ReleaseStrategy releaseStrategy = (ReleaseStrategy) directFieldAccessor.getPropertyValue("releaseStrategy");
DirectFieldAccessor dfa = new DirectFieldAccessor(releaseStrategy); 
dfa.setPropertyValue("expression", ...);
```

Anyway, it isn't clear, why you need such a perversion...

Comment: Thank you Artem, I used the directFieldAccessor and I'm trying to get the 'release-strategy-expression' and 'group-timeout' attributes from the aggregator, but the problem is that I can't access those fields:  public void setAggregatorConfiguration(String aggregatorName, int aggregationThreshold, long aggregationTimeout) {

        EventDrivenConsumer aggregator = getAggregator(aggregatorName);
        DirectFieldAccessor directFieldAccessor = new DirectFieldAccessor(aggregator);        directFieldAccessor.setPropertyValue("group-timeout", aggregationTimeout);
    }